# Replace a digit in a string with a symbol

Tags: c

The following code reads and finds the digit 1. My question is how could it be replaced with a symbol (say 'a') and printed back with the replaced ones.

```
int i, newtxt;
    char text[100];
    printf("Enter text: ");
    gets(text);
    for(i = 0; i<strlen(text); i++)
    {
        if(text[i] == '1')
            replace with a?
    }
    printf("%s", newtxt);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seriously? With all of the rest of the code, you had to ask on StackOverflow for the one line to replace the value of `text[i]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
if(text[i] == '1')
        text[i] = 'a';
```

And do not use `gets`. Its unsafe. Use `fgets` instead.

```
fgets(text, 100, stdin);
```

Also

```
printf("%s", newtxt);
```

is wrong. You have to fix this (try it your self).

Comment: What would be a proper solution for the last one?

Comment: Think over it why it is wrong. If I spoon feed you this time then it is not gonna help you in future. **Hint:** *`newtxt` is neither a `char` array nor a pointer to `char`*.

Comment: Do not worry. If you will fail to fix the problem , then I will explain it latter :)

Comment: Well, **puts(text)** did the job, as well as **char text[100], *newtxt=text; printf("%s", newtxt);** Thanks a lot for answers! Was the last one your solution anyway?

Comment: Yes. I mean to say that.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace it like this:

```
 if(text[i] == '1')
     text[i] = 'a';
```